# Retrieve randomly preformatted text from Text File

Tags: python, regex, gettext

I am writing a python script to get a string formatted as `StartTime="mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ccc"` and `EndTime="mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ccc"` located in a text file.

So I proceed to search for `StartTime` and `Endtime` but how can I get what's after (`="mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ccc"`) ? When I get the `StartTime` and `EndTime` strings I want to save them in another text file with a function `saveIntoFile(File, textToSave)` but I think I'll be able to deal with this part myself.

```
def getTimeCode(File) :
    fopen = open(File, 'r')    
    text = fopen.read()
    for t in text :
        if t == "StartTime" :
            #what should I do now ?
        if t == "EndTime" :
            #what should I do now ?

def saveIntoFile(filename, textToSave):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def getTimeCode(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            m = re.search(r'(\w)="(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\d)"', line)
            if m:
                if m.group(1) == 'StartTime':
                    # do something with m.group(2)
                elif m.group(1) == 'EndTime':
                    # do something with m.group(2)
                else:
                    # m.group(1) unknown
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the really quick answer :)