# Python Regex use during specific string search in a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have to find an expression in a text file like : `StartTime="4/11/2013 8:11:20:965" and EndTime="4/11/2013 8:11:22:571"`

So I used the regex expression

```
r'(\w)="(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2,3})"'
```

Thanks again to eumiro for his help earlier ([Retrieve randomly preformatted text from Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172247/retrieve-randomly-preformatted-text-from-text-file))

But I can't find anything in my file, and I checked it was there.

I can't go trhough 'GetDuration lvl 1' with it actually.

I tried to simplify my regex as `r'(\d)'`, and it worked to lvl 4, so I thought it could be and issue with eventually protected `"` but I didn't see anything about this in python doc.

What am I missing ?

```
Regular_Exp = r'(\w)="(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2,3})"'

def getDuration(timeCode1, timeCode2)
    duration =0
    c = ''
    print 'GetDuration lvl 0'
    for c in str(timeCode1) :
        m = re.search(Regular_Exp, c)
        print 'GetDuration lvl 1'

        if m:
            print 'GetDuration lvl 2'
            for text in str(timeCode2) :
                print 'GetDuration lvl 3'
                n = re.search(Regular_Exp, c)
                if n:
                    print 'GetDuration lvl 4'
                    timeCode1Split = timeCode1.split(' ')
                    timeCode1Date = timeCode1Split[0].split('/')
                    timeCode1Heure = timeCode1Split[1].split(':')

                    timeCode2Split = timeCode2.split(' ')
                    timeCode2Date = timeCode2Split[0].split('/')
                    timeCode2Heure = timeCode2Split[1].split(':')

                    timeCode1Date = dt.datetime(timeCode1Date[0], timeCode1Date[1], timeCode1Date[2], timeCode1Heure[0], timeCode1Heure[0], timeCode1Heure[0], tzinfo=utc)
                    timeCode2Date = dt.datetime(timeCode2Date[0], timeCode2Date[1], timeCode2Date[2], timeCode2Heure[0], timeCode2Heure[0], timeCode2Heure[0], tzinfo=utc)

                    print 'TimeCode'
                    print timeCode1Date
                    print timeCode2Date

                duration += timeCode1Date - timeCode2Date

    return duration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for c in str(timeCode1) :
    m = re.search(Regular_Exp, c)

    ...
```

`for x in str(something)` means you're iterating `something` character by character (one character=1 length `str` at a time), and no regex can match with that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this exp should help:

```
"(\w+?)=\"(.+?)\""
```

TO use:

```
>>> string = u'StartTime="4/11/2013 8:11:20:965" and EndTime="4/11/2013 8:11:22:571"'
>>> regex = re.compile("(\w+?)=\"(.+?)\"")
# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[(u'StartTime', u'4/11/2013 8:11:20:965'), (u'EndTime', u'4/11/2013 8:11:22:571')]
```

Also, `for c in str(timeCode1)`, try printing `c`, you are going one character at a time, not a good idea with regex..

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try something else :)